# UIViewController Hierarchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, delegates

If there are multiple views - say view 1, view 2, view 3, view 4 and view 5, and they are in a navigation stack with view 5 being the present view (which is on top), How can I access a method written in view3 in the controller for view5? Is it done like creating the instance of controller of view3 in the view5 controller and then call the method? But thats not the ideal approach I beleive. Whats the best approach for this scenario?

Comment: What does the method that you want to call do?

Comment: Its just any other instance method.

Comment: What I'm fishing for is the method's scope.  Basically if the method in view3 is a general-use method, needed in more than one place, it probably does not belong in a view controller, but in some utility class.

Comment: The method that view 5 would like to call, does it depend on the state of view 3; i.e. does it matter if, say, you make this method available to a base class and view1....view5 derive from this base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can access that by accessing navigation controller stack-

```
NSMutableArray *activeControllerArray = [self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

Controller3 myController;
For(int i = 0, i <[activeControllerArray  count], i++) {
    if([[activeViewController objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[Controller3 class]) {
        myController = [activeViewController objectAtIndex:i];
     }
}
```

Now you can perform actions that you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSMutableArray *controllers = [[self.navigationController.viewControllers mutableCopy] autorelease];

ABCController *controller = [controllers objectAtIndex:2]; //ABCController is the name of conroller class
[controller methodName] ;
```

this approach should work

Answer (score 0):

I suggest making a base class from which view1, view2,...view 5 will derive.  The base class will contain this method making it accessible to all the classes (view1, view2,...)